# Button to add content to other page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a POS system with HTML, CSS and Javascript.
I currently have a site that loads in the inventory to an iframe and from there I want the buttons from the iframe to add their information such as "Name, price, amount etc." to another div.
Is this possible?

I already tired linking the target and such, but nothing worked.

Index page:

```
<wrapper>
    <div id="category">
        <a href="øl_soda.html" target="iframe1">
            <input type="button" class="categories_button" value="Øl/Soda" />
        </a>
        <a href="drinks.html" target="iframe1">
            <input type="button" class="categories_button" value="Drinks" />
        </a>
        <a href="shot.html" target="iframe1">
            <input type="button" class="categories_button" value="Shots" />
        </a>
        <a href="diverse.html" target="iframe1">
            <input type="button" class="categories_button" value="Diverse" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <iframe name="iframe1" id="inventory" src="velkommen.html">
    </iframe>

    <div id="checkout">
        <ul id="myList">
            <li>
                Ja
            </li>
        </ul>

        <button onclick="remove()">Remove</button>
        <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
</wrapper>
```

Site open in iframe:

```
<script>
    function add_rynkeby() {
        var node = document.createElement("LI");
        var textnode = document.createTextNode("Rynkeby");
        node.appendChild(textnode);
        document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
    }

    function add_cocio() {
        var node = document.createElement("LI");
        var textnode = document.createTextNode("Cocio");
        node.appendChild(textnode);
        document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
    }

    function remove() {
        var list = document.getElementById("myList");
        list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
    }
</script>

<script>
    function reset() {
        var list = document.getElementById("myList");
        while (list.hasChildNodes()) {
            list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
        }
    }
</script>

<wrapper>

    <button onclick="add_rynkeby()" class="inventory_button" target="index.html">Rynkeby</button>

</wrapper>
```

So I want the buttons from the iframe site to display it's name into the "checkout" div on the index page.

Comment: `<input>` is not a valid child of `<a>`. Beyond that the term *"it's not working"* is virtually meaningless. What does happen....what errors are thrown? You need to narrow this down considerably to far more specific part of the code and provide basic debugging details

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

To have the page in the iframe communicate information to the parent page, use the **postMessage** API. MDN page is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage but searching for "postmessage api" will turn up many guides.

The general idea is:

- the iframed page's JS sends a message when the button is clicked
- the parent page's JS listens for messages, and responds in some way when it recognizes a received message as coming from the iframe

That "recognizes a received message as coming from the iframe" is an important security point: you'll need to set things up so that the parent page only trusts the messages you intend it to trust. Most guides to the API will cover that.